# How to connect heroku to mongodb in gradle Springboot REST app?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, heroku, gradle

I followed this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) to set up a gradle Springboot service with mongoDB, then followed the [deployment instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku#preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-heroku) for heroku. I also added the mongoLab addOn. It works perfectly on localhost, but when database parts are reached on heroku, the responses stall indefinitely. When I remove the mongoDB lines and re-deploy, the responses work perfectly. How can I deploy this app to heroku with mongoDB working?

EDIT: this is the error from heroku logs

`org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out`

Comment: Can you share the lines you are removing to make the app work?

Comment: I added the project in it's entirety. For example in the GameController, at the "/create" endpoint, when I remove the line that says `database.save(board);` it works, but when that line is there, it doesnt work. 

This works perfectly fine locally, but not on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a mongoLab configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoLabConfiguration {

  public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws MongoException, UnknownHostException {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(System.getenv("MONGODB_URI")));
  }
  public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
  }
}
```